# Seeking Global Projection in Meters?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, vector-grid

Currently I only have a GCS (WGS84), but it only allows for decimal degrees. Is there a global projection or CRS that would allow me to use Meters as a measurement?

I am using this for a tool that doesn't accept a linear unit (Value and Unit), but only a double and bases it off the CRS.

Comment: Have you tried WGS84 Web Mercator Auxiliary Sphere? It's linear unit is in Meters. Also, what exactly are you trying to do - reproject, measure in ArcMap, run a geoprocessing tool?

Comment: I am trying to run the CreateFishnet Tool and create 200 meter boxes, but I can't convert decimal degrees to meters.

Comment: I have tried this projection. It changes the measurements to meters, but distorts the image from the original data. Is there any way to an on the fly conversion without ruining the integrity of the data?

Comment: No projected CRS will maintain distances everywhere so although Create Fishnet will make them, they won't really be 200 m "on the ground." Possibly Robinson or Winkel Tripel or Equidistant cylindrical, but even the last one maintains distances only along standard parallels and north-south (along meridians/longitudes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no projection that can be consistent without distortion at global scale. This is the main reason of having so many projections. The distortion will always exist in *shape*, *area*, *distance* and *direction*. You can choose a projection that can preserve one of the four parameters, but the other three parameters will be distorted. You can refer to [Understanding Map Projections](http://gis.icao.int/icaoetod/map_projections[1].pdf) for more information.

One possible solution that you can define a cell size in decimal degree (DD) which will be **approximately** 200 meter depending on the target location. An approximate cell size of 0.002 DD will equal approximately 200 m. You can refer to the [Decimal degrees in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees) article that explains how the conversion of DD to meter will vary depending on the location. For example 0.002 will equal:

1. 222.64 m (N/S or E/W at equator)
2. 204.94 m (E/W at 23N/S)
3. 157.42 m (E/W at 45N/S)
4. 86.992 m (E/W at 67N/S)

However, the above values will be also different when you convert the grid from geographic to a specific projection. so you have to take care about that.